# How to specify horizontal space size

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, vertical-alignment

I'm learning `pdfLaTeX`, I've tried `\hfill`, but it makes text after `\hfill` on the line at right side.
More specifically, I want to make something like shown in attached picture

[image].

Comment: IMHO this forum isn't the textbook of TeX. Do you read something basic about TeX? If so, then you know `\vskip`, `\hskip` etc. commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With questions like this it is always a very good idea to also post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows us what you have so far and helps us better understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could very conveniently be handled by left-aligned under-stacks.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\bigskip
\noindent\Longunderstack{
[Name]\cr
[Designation]\cr
Address Line 1.,\cr
Address Line 2.,\cr
Address Line 3.
}
\hfill
\Longunderstack{
[Name]\cr
[Designation]\cr
Address Line 1.,\cr
Address Line 2.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  {\centering\LARGE\bfseries Certificate \par}

  \lipsum[1-2]

  \vfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
  Name\\
  Designation\\
  Address\\
  Address\\
  Address
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
  Name\\
  Designation\\
  Address\\
  Address\\
  Address
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By removing some of the address lines from one of the two `tabular` block,  it seems that both `Name` won't be placed on same line.

Comment: @user148865 Add `[t]` like `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}` for both `tabular`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. I'm using `\quad` to insert some space left and right of the names in the table. Without them, the table would align with the text borders. This is just a matter of taste. The `\hfill` pushes the tables to the left and right such that you don't have to specify an explicit width for the white space in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Certificate}
\end{center}
\bigskip

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet.
\bigskip

\noindent\leavevmode
\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
Short\\
Designation\\
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l}
First Middle Longname\\
Designation\\
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
\end{tabular}
\quad
\end{document}
```

[image]